Why when running two Selenium WebDriver Java Builds in Jenkins at the same time, build #1 passes, #2 has blank chrome page "Not Secure Data:," message
I recently upgraded Jenkins from 2.3xx to 2.452.1
Prior to the upgrade, I was able to run multiple Selenium Java builds at the same time resulting in multiple Chrome Browsers running interactively. I was previously able to run up to 5 Selenium Builds resulting in 5 Chrome browsers running at the same time without error. BTW, each build is using TestNG scripts. Each TestNG scripts run different tests.
Now, when I run multiple builds, the first Chrome Browser window appears/runs/passes, but when a (any) second build starts to run, Chrome launches a second browser with a blank page with the message "Not Secure Data:," in the address bar. This build ultimately fails.
Independently, the jobs run fine without error, but when I run in parallel, the 2nd job always fails. If I then try again switching the order of the two builds, then the build that had previously failed, will now pass since it is run first, and the build that had passed in the first run will now fail since it is the second build.
Finally, the target website is a PHP site running Laravel.
Please Help,
Thanks!
I've been trying to find similar issues online, but can't find a situation like mine.
I tried a bunch of ChromeOptions like:
I had tried various combinations of the below. Nothing worked with Chrome.
Interestingly, Firefox GeckcoDriver does work in parallel, but we need it to work in Chrome
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary",chromeDriverPath);  
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
webdriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);  
driver.get(url); 

// I also tried chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes');
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors"); 

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

...
